# How to detect a player's height when floating?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I want to make a command that, when used, detects how high above the ground I'm floating and then teleports me to the ground.
But I'm not sure how to detect how high the player is above ground.

Comment: Welcome to Arqade! What have you tried so far?

Comment: well I haven't tried anything really as the only thing I could find is how to detect y value which would be useful only if I know the ground y value

Comment: Are datapack annswers fine? Also, what happens if they are above void?

Comment: datapack answer is fine, if they are above void just do nothing it doesnt really matter

Answer (score 2):

I tried a few versions and this one seems the best. As datapack called `tp` and function `ground.mcfunction`, do:

`ground.mcfunction`

```
execute align y unless block ~ ~-1 ~ air run tp @s ~ ~ ~
execute positioned ~ ~-1 ~ if block ~ ~ ~ air run function tp:ground
```

It basically moves a block down, if it is grounded, tp the player, if not, move one block down and run the function from those coordinates.

If you want to run the command for a player/entity, just do:

```
/execute as [YourTarger] at @s run function tp:ground
```